Next.js API Not Fetching Updated Secrets in Both Development and Production
I'm using Next.js to build a backend API, and I'm facing an issue where my secrets are not getting updated. I have a getSecrets function in my utils folder that retrieves secrets, but it seems to always return outdated values. This problem persists both in development and production environments.
import { Env_Keys } from "@/types/customType";
import { DefaultAzureCredential } from "@azure/identity";
import { SecretClient } from "@azure/keyvault-secrets";

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
const vaultName = "";
const url = `https://${vaultName}.vault.azure.net`;
const client = new SecretClient(url, credential);

let secrets: Env_Keys | null = null;

async function getSecrets() {
  if (secrets === null) {
    const secretNames = [
      "Test",
    ];

    const secretPromises = secretNames.map((secretName) =>
      client
        .getSecret(secretName)
        .then((secret) => ({ [secretName]: secret.value }))
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(`Failed to get secret ${secretName}: ${error}`);
          return { [secretName]: null };
        })
    );

    const secretObjects = await Promise.all(secretPromises);

    secrets = Object.assign({}, ...secretObjects);
  }

  return secrets;
}

export default getSecrets;


import getSecrets from "@/lib/read-keyvaults-secrets";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

export async function GET() {
  try {
    const secrets = await getSecrets();
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        secrets: {
          ...secrets,
          date: new Date().toISOString(),
        },
      },
      {
        status: 200,
        statusText: "OK",
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        error: "An error occurred while fetching the secrets",
      },
      {
        status: 500,
        statusText: "Internal Server Error",
      }
    );
  }
}

I am getting outdated value of Test secret.
Could there be caching issues or something specific to Next.js that I’m missing?

The current implementation caches the retrieved secrets in the secrets variable. This can lead to outdated values if secrets are updated frequently. To prevent caching, modify getSecrets to fetch secrets on every call
Remove the caching mechanism to always fetch fresh secrets:
Updated code:
async function getSecrets() {
  const secretNames = ["Test"];

  const secretPromises = secretNames.map((secretName) =>
    client
      .getSecret(secretName)
      .then((secret) => ({ [secretName]: secret.value }))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`Failed to get secret ${secretName}: ${error}`);
        return { [secretName]: null };
      })
  );

  const secretObjects = await Promise.all(secretPromises);

  return Object.assign({}, ...secretObjects);
}


so when we deploy our application at that time once it will fetch these secrets and after it will give cache values?
